# Dynamically chose arguments to Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I have two classes that inherit from the same parent class

```
class parent:
    @abstractmethod
    def update(self):
        pass

class child1(parent):
    def update(self):
        do_something

class child2(parent):
    def update(self):
        do_something_else
```

And a script similar to the following

```
child = either child1() or child2() depending on some condition
a = func_a()
b = func_b()
c = func_c()
d = func_d()
```

In that script I want to call `child.update()` and pass some arguments to it. These arguments could be `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` or a combination of them, **depending on the type of child** which can be `child1` or `child2`. The number of these needed arguments also differs.

What is the cleanest way to adapt which arguments are passed to the `update` method depending on this condition ?

I want to avoid complex `if, elif` conditions (since my real code is bigger than this example), I thought of passing all possible arguments as a dict and then choosing which ones to use in the `update` method but I don't like it either.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword arguments provides a clean solution for this kind of problem:

```py
class parent:
    @abstractmethod
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        pass

class child1(parent):
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs['a'])
        print(kwargs['b'])

class child2(parent):
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs['a'])
        print(kwargs['c'])
        print(kwargs['d'])

c = child1()
c.update(a=2, b=3)

c = child2()
c.update(a=3, d='e', c=3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is more in the script side. "c" can be a child1 or child2 and I need to adapt the update call to the required arguments, like : c.update(required arguments depending on c class)

Comment: Why not just always pass all the arguments and only pull the ones out of `kwargs` that you need?

Comment: kwargs is also a dictionary so you can create a specific dictionary `d` according to the type of object you want to create and then call `c.update(**d)`.